# SSRS ReportServer and Portal returns 401 error

Tags: iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm getting a 401 Http error when accessing both the ReportServer and Portal URLs for SSRS. I get prompted with a Windows authentication prompt and then it returns 401 after logging in. It was working and I'm not sure what changed.

Also on Windows 11 my account is connected via SSO to my work domain. SSRS has given an error when I logged in. When I last used a work account it worked however I can't find a way to do this in Windows 11 anymore - `Run As Different User` throws an error.

So far I have tried a number of solutions:

- Granted Folder permissions to IUSRS group, Administrators account and AppPool user
- Checked no Authorization Rules blocking in IIS
- User exists in the ReportServer database
- Changed Anonymous Authentication Credentials from IUSR to Appliction pool identity
- Reinstalled SSRS

The service account is set to `Network Service` and `Execution Account` is not specified.

The SSRS logs don't reveal any errors.

RsReportServer.config url reservations:

```
<URLReservations>
    <Application>
        <Name>ReportServerWebService</Name>
        <VirtualDirectory>ReportServer</VirtualDirectory>
        <URLs>
            <URL>
                <UrlString>http://+:80</UrlString>
                <AccountSid>S-1-5-80-4050220999-2730734961-1537482082-519850261-379003301</AccountSid>
                <AccountName>NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices</AccountName>
            </URL>
            <URL>
                <UrlString>https://Performa-PC:443</UrlString>
                <AccountSid>S-1-5-80-4050220999-2730734961-1537482082-519850261-379003301</AccountSid>
                <AccountName>NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices</AccountName>
            </URL>
        </URLs>
    </Application>
    <Application>
        <Name>ReportServerWebApp</Name>
        <VirtualDirectory>Reports</VirtualDirectory>
        <URLs>
            <URL>
                <UrlString>http://+:80</UrlString>
                <AccountSid>S-1-5-80-4050220999-2730734961-1537482082-519850261-379003301</AccountSid>
                <AccountName>NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices</AccountName>
            </URL>
            <URL>
                <UrlString>https://Performa-PC:443</UrlString>
                <AccountSid>S-1-5-80-4050220999-2730734961-1537482082-519850261-379003301</AccountSid>
                <AccountName>NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices</AccountName>
            </URL>
        </URLs>
    </Application>
</URLReservations>
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: This seems to have been finally resolved by enabling the <RSWindowsBasic/> AuthenticationType. Now I get a new error connecting to the Report Portal: 

"The service is not available.
Could not connect to the server. Please check your network settings and try again later."

Comment: This is a new issue, please post the question in new thread.

Comment: Sorry for repurposing this question, the original 401 error I had wasn't properly resolved by changing to <RSWindowsBasic/> it just caused a different error message.

Comment: I have reverted the question back.